# NWConnection: Unable to modify the remote endpoint

Tags: swift, xcode, network-programming, udp

In order to operate the “Session Traversal Utilities for NAT” (STUN) protocol in SWIFT I first open a `NWConnection` with a remote `STUN` server of known remoteIP and remotePort like this:

```
udpConnection = NWConnection(host: remoteIp!, port: remotePort!, using: .udp)
```

Then I send and receive some packets. I modify remoteIp and remotePort and then *WITHOUT CLOSING THE CONNECTION* (in order to keep the same Local Endpoint) I try to modify the Remote Endpoint like this:

```
udpConnection?.currentPath?.remoteEndpoint = NWEndpoint.hostPort(host: remoteIp!, port: remotePort!)
```

But I receive following error:

> Cannot assign to property: 'remoteEndpoint' is a 'let' constant.

Even cancelling the current connection:

```
udpConnection?.cancelCurrentEndpoint()
```

and restarting it:

```
udpConnection?.restart()
```

does not help.

The question is: Why is remoteEndpoint a 'let' constant not allowing me to modify it?

Thanks in advance.